# Success function not working in Ext JS form submit

Tags: php, extjs

I am downloading a CSV file in my PHP code, but it not returning to my Ext JS page. My code is below:

**Ext JS Code**

```
Ext.getCmp('btnExport').on('click', function(button, event)    
{       
    Ext.getCmp("frmReportQuotes").getForm().standardSubmit = true;      
    Ext.getCmp('frmReportQuotes').getEl().dom.method = 'POST';      
    Ext.getCmp('frmReportQuotes').getEl().dom.target = '_blank';        
    Ext.getCmp('frmReportQuotes').getForm().submit({        
        params: {       
            output: 'csv'    
        },    
        success: function(form, action){        
            alert('jjkjlkj');           
        },    
        failure: function(form, action){    
            alert('jjkjlkj');           
        }    
    });    
});
```

**PHP Code**

```
if (!empty($strOutputType) && $strOutputType == 'csv')    
{       
    header("Content-type: text/csv");       
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv");       
    header("Pragma: no-cache");     
    header("Expires: 0");

    if (!empty($entRequestList))    
    {
        $arrKeys = array();

        foreach ($this->view->Data[0] as $key => $value)    
            $arrKeys[] = $key;

        echo '"' . implode('","', $arrKeys) . '"' . "\n";           

        foreach ($this->view->Data as $entRow)
        {
            $strCSV = '"' . implode('","', $entRow) . '"';
            $strCSV = preg_replace("[\n\r]", " ", $strCSV);
            echo $strCSV . "\n";
        }
    }

    die();
}
```

Please help, so that it returns back to my Ext JS file.

Comment: This isn't a place where people debug your code for you. Identify a specific problem that you can't figure out, and then ask about it. Show people what you've already tried, list your steps, etc. Basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you are returning a CSV file attachment you cant expect it to be processed by the ajax request handler, so don't expect your success function to run.

Also from the docs:

```
standardSubmit : Boolean
```

> If set to true, a standard HTML form submit is used instead of a XHR
>   (Ajax) style form submission.

Which means no js callback will be made.